# Is there a way to conveniently check what values are assigned to all the constants after compiling a code with ARM C?

Tags: c, arm

I'm compiling c code with ARM processor.

I need to check constant value which is defined differently under different switch. There is tool to compile for multiple configurations. Thinking of whether can get the constant value from the compilation result files, or purposely create some operations, and read the dis-assembled result. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Not so familiar with ARM instructions yet. Looks like not all instruction expose the constant value in a straightforward way.

Comment: If you explicitly declare all such variables as `volatile const` and place them in a custom section using a linker script, they should end up in a contiguous chunk easily viewed in the debugger. And from the debugger you can export the memory map.

Comment: I would say there is no convenient way to do it.  There are numerous inconvenient ways to do it.

Comment: Can your assembler generate a listing file?

Answer (score 1):

GCC and Clang have the ability to [include arbitrary text in their assembly output](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html#Using-Assembly-Language-with-C) and to include various values in that text.

Inside any function, include these lines:

```
#if GenerateConstants
    __asm__("# MyConstant = %c0" : : "i" (MyConstant));
#endif
```

Then compile with the switches `-DGenerateConstants` and `-S`. The compiler will generate a file named `SourceFileName.s`, and you can use `-o Name` to give it a different name if desired.

Then `grep " MyConstant =" Name` will find this line, showing something like:

```
    ## MyConstant = 17
```

Then you can use `sed` or other tools to extract the value.

In the `__asm__`, `"i"` says to generate an “immediate” operand. The `(MyConstant)` that follows that gives the value it should have. In the first quoted string, `%c0` is replaced with the value of that operand.

The `0` indicates which operand to replace—if there were more than one listed later in the `__asm__`, they are numbered 0, 1, 2, 3, and so on. (There is also a mechanism for naming them instead of numbering them, not shown here.) Normally, `%0` would be replaced by the form of immediate operand suitable for the target assembly language, such as `$17` or `#17`. However, the `c` modifier says to use the bare constant, so the replacement text is just the value, in this example, `17`.

The example above includes `#` to mark a comment in assembly language. Clang at least (I did not test GCC) may transform this for the target assembly language. Testing on an ARM Mac showed `; MyConstant = 17` in the assembly output. This is why I did not include the `#` in the `grep` pattern above.

The `#if GenerateConstants` is to keep the extra text out of ordinary builds, but you can omit that and leave the `__asm__` in deployment builds. It should be harmless.